# Linux search file with given name containing string recursively

Tags: linux, grep, find, string, search

From Linux shell, Let's say I'm in directory `/dir` and I want to find, recursively in all subfolders, all the files which contain in the name the string `name_string` and, inside, the string `content_string`. `name_string` might be at the beginning, center or end of the file name. How could I do that?

I was trying to sue grep as:

`grep -r content_string /dir/*name_string*`

But I haven't been lucky so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick solution, although maybe not as efficient as other methods,

```
find /dir -type f -name '*name_string*' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l content_string
```

Comment: I was pretty far from the solution. That worked just fine, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following OR syntax:

`grep -nriE '.*name_string.*|content_string' /dir`

Or do what I usually do which is piping the output of first `grep` into another `grep`:

`grep -nriE '.*name_string.*' /dir | grep -nri 'content_string'`